# LibreOffice from RPM looks ugly

Tags: fedora, libreoffice

I'm using x86-64 Fedora 18 (my desktop is KDE), that ships with LibreOffice 3.6. I wanted to install LibreOffice 4.0, thus I installed the RPMs (from [here](https://www.libreoffice.org/download-more/)). It works, but looks ugly. Compare:

1. LibreOffice 4.0 (from the RPMs): [image]
2. LibreOffice 3.6 (from the repos): [image]

I checked in the options of LibreOffice, disabled the high-contrast theme but didn't work.

[Here](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/install-libreoffice-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/) it suggests to install the package `pangox-compat`, but it's already installed.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you also change icon size and style? from Tools> Options > Libreoffice > View > User Interface > Icon size and style after you disable Automatically detect high contrast mode

Comment: @Salton this worked. Can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is caused by new accessibility option in LibreOffice 4. This option can be disabled by:

1. Tools > Options under LibreOffice > Accessibility, disable *Automatically detect high contrast mode of operating system*.
2. Tools > Options under LibreOffice > View, set *Icon size and style* to your icon set.